# Why does Odis do this?

Tags: plot-explanation, fargo-tv

In the episode *the Nadir*, having cornered the escaped prisoners Zelmare and Swanee, US Marshall Wickware asks the local detective Odis Weff to handcuff the escapees while he holds them at gunpoint -- but Odis instead shoots Wickware, then Swanee (Zelmare manages to get away).

Granted Wickware was a pain in the ass, but if Odis had done what he asked the Marshall would've left town and be a pain in someone else's ass -- what was the point in Otis shooting him?

Answer (score 1):

[As explained here](https://decider.com/2020/11/09/fargo-season-4-episode-8-recap/):

> But rather than running, the PTSD/OCD-suffering detective **Odis Weff had decided he wanted to stand and fight on the side of the law**, reclaiming the power he’d lost to his gangster paymasters. “You wanna die like a man?” Wickware says to him. “You gotta live like a man.”
>
> Unfortunately for Wickware, Odis has severely different ideas of what that entails. When he walks into the train station where the bodies of dozens of cops and civilians lie on the floor dead or dying, he tracks Wickware down to where the marshal has Zelmare and Swanee cornered. But the first person he shoots is Wickware himself. **I guess all that good-natured Mormon-scented bullying wore thin.**